# Error with reading csv from URL: Error in functionalert protocol version

Tags: r

I have a problem with getting data from URL

```
weatherExists = url.exists("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataprofessor/data/master/weather-weka.csv")
weather <- read.csv(text = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataprofessor/data/master/weather-weka.csv") )
```

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :    error:1407742E:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

This URL is valid if you copy paste it into your browser the data will show so I do not get why the function is not working properly

Comment: `weather <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataprofessor/data/master/weather-weka.csv')` works for me.

Comment: Where does the `getURL` function come from? That doesn't seem to be base R. And it also doesn't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `url` works.

```
weather <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataprofessor/data/master/weather-weka.csv"))

head(weather)
   outlook temperature humidity windy play
1    sunny          85       85 FALSE   no
2    sunny          80       90  TRUE   no
3 overcast          83       86 FALSE  yes
4    rainy          70       96 FALSE  yes
5    rainy          68       80 FALSE  yes
6    rainy          65       70  TRUE   no
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `read_csv` from `readr`

```
readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataprofessor/data/master/weather-weka.csv')
# A tibble: 14 x 5
   outlook  temperature humidity windy play 
   <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl> <chr>
 1 sunny             85       85 FALSE no   
 2 sunny             80       90 TRUE  no   
 3 overcast          83       86 FALSE yes  
 4 rainy             70       96 FALSE yes  
 5 rainy             68       80 FALSE yes  
 6 rainy             65       70 TRUE  no   
 7 overcast          64       65 TRUE  yes  
 8 sunny             72       95 FALSE no   
 9 sunny             69       70 FALSE yes
```